# I'd like to add a button to an Excel Spreadsheet which triggers some VB code to animate some cell values 

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to do the following:

1. Add a button to an Excel spreadsheet.
2. When I click the button, it automatically starts to increment cell B2 (for example) from 0 to 100, and back again, in an endless loop.
3. When I click the button again, the animation will stop.

How do I solve this problem?

Shane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a clue: http://www.s-anand.net/blog/animated-charts-in-excel/

Comment: Unfortunately, this method won't work: while the animation is playing, the cursor turns into an hourglass, which stops you using Excel.

Is there a way to run code in a thread from Excel?